# Aligning two multiline equations

Tags: math-mode, align

I searched a lot for this but couldn't find an answer. Say I have two equations that are 2 lines long each. I can align each equation at their equality sign using equation-aligned or gather-split, like this:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{split}
  a &=b \\
    &=c
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
  k &=l+55 \\
    &=d+401
\end{split}
\end{gather}
```

However, I can't find a way to align the equality signs of both sets of code. Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

Just change `gather` into `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a &=b \\
    &=c
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
  k &=l+55 \\
    &=d+401
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you pass the `tbtags` option to `amsmath`, you get the equation numbers aligned with the bottom line instead of centered on the `split`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  a &=b \\
    &=c
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
  k &=l+55 \\
    &=d+401
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]